# Fetching Data From Cloud Server

Tags: java, android, cloud, server

I am working on an android application which needs to fetch data from a cloud server . I know how to send a post request to a server and get data in return but i have never worked with cloud server before . https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html
 i have visited this website but it's not that much of help to me i am confused as to how to send request to the server and retrieve data . I don't know anything about cloud servers .

Comment: What do you mean with "cloud server"? Be more specific.

Comment: a server which retrieves data from cloud . I have no specifications right now . I just need a headstart on what to do .

Comment: So you're talking about a cloud buzzword server - they are much cooler than normal servers. Come back when you have specifications and specific problems, not buzzwords.

Comment: Hello friend... There is no difference between a "server" and a "cloud server". You just need to use the ip address of your cloud machine, and it will reply!

Answer (score 0):

A cloud server is just a normal server hosted in a some 'cloud providers' data centre. It is typically a virtual server - i.e. a single physical server running multiple virtual servers.

From your point of view you can think of it as just a regular server.

What may be causing confusion is that there are also 'Mobile Backed as a Service' providers - these allow you interact with servers, typically ones hosted in a cloud, but may allow you interact with them using a mobile SDK (or library) rather than using traditional client server communication. Your app usually needs to know nothing about the individual servers and you yourself don't need to create or manage any servers either.

Take a look here for a good overview of this latter approach:

- https://parse.com/docs/android/guide